# Apache service hung and incoming requests not accepted

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, hanging

My production server is running Apache v2.2.4 with mod_mono v1.2.4 on CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

Suddenly, Apache service hung during normal usage time (approx. 1 pm EDT). Traffic is not too high at this time.  This is the first time we're noticing this kind of behaviour in our server.  I noticed from access log that even subsequent requests are also not received, even though there were incoming requests.  I then manually tried to invoke my application call from web browser, it never returned successfully but it was still loading.

I found no unusual behaviour/activity in:
1) Apache `access_log` and `error_log`
2) No kernel level errors found in `/var/log/messages`

I've no other option but ended up restarting Apache service.

Any idea on what would cause Apache to hang and thereby not allowing subsequent incoming requests?  How do I debug/diagnose when this happens next time?

Experts advice/recommendation on this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this when there is a block on IO in the kernel. Is the Apache perhaps serving data from an NFS mount or something similar that can fail hard?

Comment: In my case, I don't think this is a block in IO. Regarding serving of data, my Apache is serving data from within my server drive which is attached permanently, and this is not a NFS mount.